# Manual Rollup (Sum) behaving differently than Reports and AggregateResult Sum

Tags: apex, reporting, aggregate, multi-currency, aggregateresult

I'm not sure what is going on here. I'm wrote/summed up some anonymous apex to demonstrate some the discrepancies I'm seeing. Sometimes the values are accurate, sometimes close, sometimes just way off.
For example in my January figures, the numbers line up 100% with Apex generated output and SFDC reports/AggregateResult approach.

January:

USD 21,952,193.06

USD 21,952,193.06

However for February, the values are considerably different. We do have multicurrency enabled, but I'm not sure if that is what is causing this discrepancy...

February:

USD 12,974,526.00

USD 12,673,184.00 (-2% difference)

```
Financial_Orders_Data__c jan = [select Id, Name, First_Day_of_Month__c, Last_Day_of_Month__c from
 Financial_Orders_Data__c where name LIKE '%January%'
];
Financial_Orders_Data__c feb = [select Id, Name, First_Day_of_Month__c, Last_Day_of_Month__c from
 Financial_Orders_Data__c where name LIKE '%February%'
];
Decimal totalRollupJan = 0;
List < OpportunityLineItem > PCPLossesJan = [select id, TotalPrice, Opportunity.Opportunity__c, Opportunity.CloseDate, Product_Family__c from OpportunityLineItem WHERE Opportunity.RecordType.Name = 'PCP'
 and Opportunity.StageName = 'Closed Lost - No Order'
 and Product_Family__c LIKE '%PCP%'
 and Opportunity.WSC__c = false and Opportunity.CloseDate >= : jan.First_Day_of_Month__c AND Opportunity.CloseDate <= : jan.Last_Day_of_Month__c
];
for (OpportunityLineItem oli: PCPLossesJan) {
 totalRollupJan += oli.TotalPrice;
}
AggregateResult[] sumOfTotalPriceJan = [select SUM(TotalPrice) from OpportunityLineItem WHERE Opportunity.RecordType.Name = 'PCP'
 and Opportunity.StageName = 'Closed Lost - No Order'
 and Product_Family__c LIKE '%PCP%'
 and Opportunity.WSC__c = false and Opportunity.CloseDate >= : jan.First_Day_of_Month__c AND Opportunity.CloseDate <= : jan.Last_Day_of_Month__c
];
system.debug('sumOfTotalPrice=' + sumOfTotalPriceJan[0]);
//sumOfTotalPrice=AggregateResult:{expr0=2.195219306E7}
//(2.195219306E7 = 23018985.04)
system.debug('value jan= ' + totalRollupJan);
//value jan= 21952193.06
//values MATCH

Decimal totalRollupFeb = 0;
List < OpportunityLineItem > PCPLossesFeb = [select id, TotalPrice, Opportunity.Opportunity__c, Opportunity.CloseDate, Product_Family__c from OpportunityLineItem WHERE Opportunity.RecordType.Name = 'PCP'
 and Opportunity.StageName = 'Closed Lost - No Order'
 and Product_Family__c LIKE '%PCP%'
 and Opportunity.WSC__c = false and Opportunity.CloseDate >= : feb.First_Day_of_Month__c AND Opportunity.CloseDate <= : feb.Last_Day_of_Month__c
];
for (OpportunityLineItem oli: PCPLossesFeb) {
 totalRollupFeb += oli.TotalPrice;
}
AggregateResult[] sumOfTotalPriceFeb = [select SUM(TotalPrice) from OpportunityLineItem WHERE Opportunity.RecordType.Name = 'PCP'
 and Opportunity.StageName = 'Closed Lost - No Order'
 and Product_Family__c LIKE '%PCP%'
 and Opportunity.WSC__c = false and Opportunity.CloseDate >= : feb.First_Day_of_Month__c AND Opportunity.CloseDate <= : feb.Last_Day_of_Month__c
];
system.debug('sumOfTotalPrice=' + sumOfTotalPriceFeb[0]);
//sumOfTotalPrice=AggregateResult:{expr0=1.297452604E7}
//(1.297452604E7 = 12974526.04)
system.debug('value feb= ' + totalRollupFeb);
//value feb= 12673184.00
//12974526.04 != 12673184.00 ?? why are these different?
//values differ by 2%...?
```

Answer (score 0):

Opportunities Owned by Inactive Owner or Opportunity Owner having no Role are not present in SFDC Standard reports.

Apex doesn't consider if Owner is active or not, thus your report from APEX is accurate.

Assign active users to opportunities which have inactive owners.

PS: Can you check if Role Hierarchy for that report is set to the highest role possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since our org has multi-currency enabled, the issue was that the non USD line items were causing the manual roll-ups to calculate differently. That explains why "sometimes the values were accurate" (because those instances were all in USD.)

I was able to fix it by using an alias in the SOQL convertCurrency(TotalPrice) ConvertedTotalPrice and casting it to a Double.

```
//Decimal pcpLossesAndDropsRollUp = 0;
Decimal pcpLossesAndDropsRollUpInUSD = 0;

List<OpportunityLineItem> pcpLossesAndDrops = [select id, TotalPrice, convertCurrency(TotalPrice) ConvertedTotalPrice, Opportunity.Opportunity__c, Opportunity.CloseDate, Product_Family__c from OpportunityLineItem WHERE Opportunity.RecordType.Name = 'PCP' and (Opportunity.StageName ='Closed Lost - No Order' or Opportunity.StageName ='Dropped') and Product_Family__c LIKE '%PCP%' and Opportunity.WSC__c = false and Opportunity.CloseDate >= :fodRecordOld.First_Day_of_Month__c AND Opportunity.CloseDate <= :fodRecordOld.Last_Day_of_Month__c];
for (OpportunityLineItem oli : pcpLossesAndDrops){
    //pcpLossesAndDropsRollUp += oli.TotalPrice;
    pcpLossesAndDropsRollUpInUSD += (Double) oli.get('ConvertedTotalPrice');
}
```